# No me descarga archivo Response.TransmitFile()

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, fileupload

estoy tratando de descargar un archivo, he tratado varias soluciones pero todos los caminos llevan a StackOverflow, mi problema es el siguiente:

Tengo el codigo listo para descargar, se descarga de un fichero interno de mi PC pero este no lo descarga. Obtengo el nombre del archivo desde una Gridview

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        
        if (e.CommandName == "Descargar")
        {
            try
            {
                int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                GridViewRow gr;
                
                gr = gvCorrelativo1.Rows[index];
                string nombrearchivo = gr.Cells[0].Text;
                Response.Clear();
                string ruta = "/documentos/" + nombrearchivo.Trim();
                Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + nombrearchivo.Trim());
                string path = Server.MapPath(ruta);

                
                Response.Flush();
                Response.TransmitFile(path);

                Response.End();
                Response.Clear();




            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex.Message);
                Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
            }
            
           
        }
        
    }
```

El problema que cuando trato de descargar el archivo. Este error pasa cuando entra a la linea de `Response.End();` y no se descarga  . al capturar el error me sale lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y el error que me sale interno es el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[EDIT]

[image: El]

existe el archivo y las rutas de la Debug

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y la ruta
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[EDIT 2]

Se adjunta la Gridview para ver si falta algo

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCorrelativo1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand" Width="532px" Height="169px"
         OnSelectedIndexChanging="gvCorrelativo1_SelectedIndexChanging"
         OnRowDeleting="gvCorrelativo1_RowDeleting"
         >

         <Columns>
             <asp:BoundField HeaderText="NombreArchivo" AccessibleHeaderText="NombreArchivo" DataField="NombreArchivo" />
             <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" Text="Descargar" CommandName="Descargar" />
             <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" Text="Eliminar" CommandName="Borrar" />
             <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" Visible="False" DataField="ID" />
             <asp:BoundField HeaderText="correlativo" DataField="correlativo" Visible="False" />
             <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true" ButtonType="Image" SelectImageUrl="~/images/Icono/descargar2.png" />
         </Columns>
     </asp:GridView>
```

El agregue lo siguiente y descarga el archivo pero me sigue tirando al catch , ADVERTENCIA: llegue y lo copie, trate de quitar las etiquetas que no estan abiertas pero deja de funcionar

```
    </ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="gvCorrelativo1" />
    </Triggers>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: ¿Existe el archivo en la ruta que tienes? ¿Sí? ¿No?, sea como sea, incluye la información que contiene la ruta del archivo, del mismo modo incluye la información del path. Por otro lado, ¿Por qué utilizas Flush y después del End, un Clear?

Comment: @fredyfx acabo de agregar las rutas y la foto de la pantalla de la ruta de la carpeta

Comment: @fredyfx Ocupo el flush por evitar errores que me daba el End, y el clear para limpiar el buffer

Comment: Pregunta express, para ver una alternativa... ya que solo necesitas descargar y no realizas niguna otra accion GridView1_RowCommand > DEscargar (solo transfieres el archivo). Porque en el gridview en vez de recuperar el valor y disparar un comando, no armas directamente ahi un "enlace" comun un corriente que apunte a la URL del archivo (esto suponiendo que los archivos estan en una carpeta dentro del sitio web, ¿es asi?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto:

```
int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
GridViewRow gr;
                
gr = gvCorrelativo1.Rows[index];
string nombrearchivo = gr.Cells[0].Text;

Response.Clear();

string ruta = "/documentos/" + nombrearchivo.Trim();
                Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + nombrearchivo.Trim());

string path = Server.MapPath(ruta);

                
Response.Flush();
Response.TransmitFile(path);

Response.End();
Response.Clear();
```

Reemplaza por:

```
int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
GridViewRow gr;
                
gr = gvCorrelativo1.Rows[index];
string nombrearchivo = gr.Cells[0].Text;

string ruta = "/documentos/" + nombrearchivo.Trim();

Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", 
   string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", nombrearchivo.Trim()));

string path = Server.MapPath(ruta);

Response.TransmitFile(path);

Response.End();
```

Si te sigue dando errores, edita tu pregunta y agrega todo lo demás que sea necesario para reproducir tu escenario.

Comment: No lo descarga, adjuntare la gridview del asp , para poder mejorar la pregunta

Comment: @FranciscoHernandez Buen día estimado, ¿realmente se resolvió tu pregunta con esta respuesta?